# Retrieving stored procedure output parameter via ADO

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures, ado

I'm stuck with this for more than 48 Hrs now. I'm trying to retrieve a output parameter value using ADO objects. here is my vba code.

```
Function ExecuteCommand(cSp As String, aParameters As Variant) As Integer

Dim lnReturn As Integer
Dim loCommand As ADODB.Command
Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter
Dim rds As ADODB.Recordset

Set loCommand = New ADODB.Command

loCommand.CommandText = cSp
loCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
Set loCommand.ActiveConnection = goConnection
loCommand.NamedParameters = True

Dim iCount As Integer

For iCount = LBound(aParameters) To UBound(aParameters)
    If aParameters(iCount, 0) <> "" Then
        If aParameters(iCount, 1) = adNumeric Then
            Set prm = loCommand.CreateParameter(aParameters(iCount, 0), aParameters(iCount, 1), adParamInput)
            prm.Precision = 18
            prm.NumericScale = 0
            prm.Value = aParameters(iCount, 3)
        Else
            Set prm = loCommand.CreateParameter(aParameters(iCount, 0), aParameters(iCount, 1), adParamInput, , aParameters(iCount, 3))
        End If
        loCommand.Parameters.Append prm
    End If
Next

Set prm = loCommand.CreateParameter("@returnval", adInteger, adParamOutput, , lnReturn)
loCommand.Parameters.Append prm

Set rds = loCommand.Execute
' Check the value of lnReturn and it's zero here.
lnReturn = loCommand.Parameters("@returnval").Value


ExecuteCommand = lnReturn

End Function
```

---

My stored procedure as follows...

```
USE [table_name]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spname]
@para1 int,
@para2 int,
@para3 int,
@returnval int Output
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT * FROM type_table WHERE type1=@para1 and type2=@para2 and type3=@para3
SET @returnval = @@ROWCOUNT
RETURN @returnval
END
```

---

These are my findings

```
lnReturn = 0 always
rds.EOF = False
rds.RecordCount = -1
```

My question is I'm not getting the correct affected row count which is 1. I'm not sure what is wrong with the code and can someone give me a hand?

Comment: Using 32767 for the integer return param size is wrong, the size argument is the maximum size in chars/bytes. Leave it empty to use the default or explicitly pass 4 (bytes in a 32bit int).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out and I modified the code to pass the empty size. But it did not add any difference for the issue i'm facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably because, as Technet says,  [In the case of output parameters and return values, the values are not returned until the data of the Recordset object has been fetched completely or the Recordset has been closed.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905903(v=sql.80).aspx)

Either close your RecordSet (`rds.Close`), if you're not interested in the data returned by the SELECT statement, or loop through it until you've read all rows.

As an aside, if you are never interested in the data returned by the select statement, only the row count, then it's more efficient not to return it.  So if you can modify your SP, you could change it to:

```
SELECT @returnval = COUNT(*) FROM type_table WHERE type1=@para1 and type2=@para2 and type3=@para3
```

Comment: I added rds.Close line just before assigning lnReturn and it's resolved the problem. so you're the hero mAn!!

Answer (score -1):

Have a try after removing  `SET NOCOUNT ON;` from your procedure

I think this will help you. The affected row count will not returned if you set `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in procedure.

Comment: I tired it already and it didn't make any difference. Also I'm getting correct values when I try to execute the SP via Management Studio regardless of SET NOCOUNT ON/OFF.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not expecting a recordset as part of your stored procedure call, use cmd1->Execute(NULL, NULL, ADO::adExecuteNoRecords);