# Extract the output variable value from stored procedure to the calling program

Tags: sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

I am trying to extract the output value from a sql stored procedure in to the calling program. The stored procedure is:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE  selectdediario (@descr varchar(20),@disp decimal output)
AS  
begin
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   SELECT @disp = sum(disp)
   FROM diario
   WHERE descr = @descr;
  return
  end
```

the output that I receive is:

```
Stored Procedure: mala2.dbo.Selectdediario
Return Code = 0
Output Parameter(s): 
@disp = 676
```

My visual basic sub procedure is in vb6.0:

```
Private Sub cmdApendTable_Click()
' declare the variable to to receive the output value of the procedure
Dim vdescr As String
vdescr = "gas sousa"

Dim vdisp As Currency

Call StartConnection

Set cmdEmpresa = New ADODB.Command
With cmdEmpresa
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@descr", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, vdescr)
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@disp money OUTPUT", adCurrency, adParamoutput)

.ActiveConnection = conexao
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.CommandText = "Selectdediario"
Set rsEmpresa = .Execute
 End With
 Debug.Print disp
End Sub
```

The program asks for the parameter `@disp` so I added it with the 0 value. I want to get the value of `@disp` into my program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving stored procedure output parameter via ADO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928509/retrieving-stored-procedure-output-parameter-via-ado)

Comment: This line  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@disp money OUTPUT", adCurrency, adParamoutput)
   looks like you would put "@disp"  not the literal string parts money and OUTPUT